Can I Generate Docker-Compose File(s) for Containers in Portainer in QNAP?
I have a QNAP TS-x53D.  I installed Container Station and Portainer.  I set up a dozen or so containers. For reasons I won't get into, I need to basically wipe the QNAP and completely redo everything.
Is there a way I can create Docker-Compose files for the containers I set up so I don't have to do it all manually again. I know you can use compose files to set up containers in Portainer, so I am quite surprised you can easily generate files from it as well.
I can do a backup via Container Station, but then the container belongs to Container Station, and that won't work.
I found https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose (from this answer) which seems like it would work. I'm not great with the console though. It requires pyaml and some other things.  To install them I need pip.  QNAP comes with Python 2.7 which doesn't have pip.  I installed python 3 via the app store, but it still loads 2.7.  I have to initiate Python 3 every time I go into the console.  I managed to get pip installed using Python 3, and I did a python3 pip -m --version, and it shows that it's there, but I cannot figure out how to actually USE pip to install `pyaml.
So I am hoping that someone has a better way/idea.
